# Page NotFound on React 17 - Context API does not appear

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I know this question was asked before, but none of the solutions provided works for me and tried many else.

My NotFound page does not appear on an inexistent route, or if a take it from switch it appears on every page. How can i fix this?

This is a demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2dtprl?file=src%2FApp.js

Thank you in advance for any ideas.
This is my code:

```
const App = () => {

    const [getSessionStorageValue] = useSessionStorage()
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(Boolean(getSessionStorageValue(SESSION_ID)))
    const value = useMemo(() => ({ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }), [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated]);

    const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => <Route {...rest} render={() => isAuthenticated ? children : <Redirect to={Urls.HOME} />} />
    const NotAuthRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => <Route {...rest} render={() => isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to={Urls.HOME} /> : children} />

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="main-container">
                <div className="body">
                    <Switch>
                        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>

                            <ProductsContextProvider>
                                <Header />
                                <Route exact path={Urls.HOME} component={Home}></Route>
                                <PrivateRoute path="must-be-authenticated-1"><PrivateComponent1 /></PrivateRoute>
                                <PrivateRoute path="must-be-authenticated-2"><PrivateComponent2 /></PrivateRoute>
                            </ProductsContextProvider>

                            <PrivateRoute path="must-be-authenticated-3"><PrivateComponent3 /></PrivateRoute>

                            <NotAuthRoute path="must-not-be-authenticated"><NotAuthComponent1 /></NotAuthRoute>

                            <Route path="general-component"><FAQ /></Route>

                        </UserContext.Provider>
                        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: You are not explaining what the desired behaviour, please make a reproducible example in a sandbox, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the desired behaviour is to render NotFound component when a user goes on a route which is not created, like www.baseUrl.com/this-route-dont-exist. The current behaviour is the the NotFound component is not rendering at all or if i put it on UserContext.Provider is rendering on every page.

Answer (score 0):

this article helped a lot: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-protect-your-routes-with-react-context-717670c4713a/
demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p71pr7jn50

Put context and header outside Switch